# Translation progress in Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, localization, liferay, translation

I am looking for a free of cost, **system**, **plugin** or any idea that can provide a progressing result after translating a content in Liferay.

I have a portlet with content written in English, and I have translated only a piece of it into Spanish. Is there a way to obtain this translation progress in order to have a translation summary?

For example, content :

English : 100% translated

Spanish : 7% translated 
... etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: How to determine text that is already translated? Do you have a set of Web-Contents (JournalArticles) and you want to display how many of those have  a certain translation? Or are we talking about language.properties?

Comment: I should be more specific. My issue is about language.properties file.

Comment: Then add this info to your question above (you can always edit your question). You should really be further more specific. What is wrong of comparing the english properties file with the spanish one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning Portlet Language.properties, you can fetch the ResourceBundle of a specific Locale and calculate percentage values with the overall amount:

`java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("content.Language", LocaleUtil.SPAIN).keySet().size()`

will give you the amount of language keys for spain language. You bundle must be referenced in your portlet.xml as `<resource-bundle>`.
For example `<resource-bundle>content.Language</resource-bundle>`

In my example "content.Language" means that your folder structure will be content/Language_es_ES.properties

Comment: Even if I have been told, with some delay(after I made my post), to search only for a management translation system due to lack of time, I will consider your answer as a helpful and right one. Thanks.